# Google Map Navigation

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, navigation

Hy there I am new to android development I want to transform google map navigation into voice mean speak to "Please Turn Left" etc during driving as most of the Navigation System do. Please tell me is there a way to do that thanks.If possible please guide me with some code...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the turn-by-turn navigation instructions? If you get them from Google request, it will provide you with the navigation instructions such as "Please Turn Left" along the Lat/Lng of where the instruction needs to be said. So if you have these data, all you have to do is: in the location listener, when the current location of the user is close to the Lat/Lng of an instruction (measure distance between the lat/lng of user and lat/lng of instruction), use TextToSpeech to speak the instruction.

You can save the instructions Lat/Lng and instruction text in two arrays and keep a counter that works as an index of what to say next.

Hope this helps, provide me with more infos in order to help you more.